# Adding shade to bussproofs' proof trees?

Tags: color, bussproofs

I am wondering how prooftree can work with colorbox? I've seen people shading their proof trees, but I am not certain what package people use. In my case, I use bussproofs, and it doesn't seem to work well with colorbox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\colorbox{gray}{
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{some law...}
\end{prooftree}
}

\end{document}
```

The code above fails. I've searched around, but the answers are either about adding color, or using bussproofs, but not both. How should I shade the whole proof tree in a box?

---

with label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{3}
  \begin{tcolorbox}
    \begin{prooftree}
      \AxiomC{some law...}
      \RightLabel{Label}
      \UnaryInfC{Some Conclusion}
    \end{prooftree}
  \end{tcolorbox}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

The box does not strictly include the label.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}
\begin{prooftree}
  \AxiomC{some law...}
\end{prooftree}
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: thanks. but it seems somehow the box just doesn't want to include the label as well. is there any way out?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr Sorry, I don't understand. There's no label even if the tcolorbox is removed.

Comment: I have labels in my actual proof trees. I've updated with an example. the problem is the box does not always include the label. I think the box wraps the region with margin, but isn't really aware of the widgets included in it. is it the case?

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr The problem is that your proof is wider than the column width. This is no different than when you have a tabular that extends outside of the page. So you need to make two columns instead of 3 in your example. You can also add an explicit `[width= ... ]` option after `\begin{tcolorbox}` to manually set the width of the box, although I suspect this shouldn't be needed. See the `tcolorbox` documentation for more details.